# Concurrent API Request Limits

Tags: oauth2, limits, authentication

While using OAuth2 for authentication/authorization to Salesforce, when we call the auth token endpoint to get a new access token using the earlier provided refresh token, does this refresh call count in the 20 seconds or 24 hours limits? Please guide if somebody knows this or direct to the correct documentation to refer.

Answer (score 2):

They all are counted against an organization API call limit. Which reset in 24 hours.

You can also check the System Overview

> Go to Monitor | System Overview and there you will find the API
>   REQUESTS, LAST 24 HOURS. This shows you how many API calls you've made
>   in the last 24 hours including today. For example, if you are viewing
>   this on Monday at 2:30 PM, it'll show you the calls made since Sunday
>   at 2:30 PM.

[API call limits and Reporting (FAQ)](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000003706&type=1)

Comment: Thanks @Tushar Sharma for the answer. Came across this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_api.htm). Here they have mentioned a exclusion list. So if not part of that, it means an automatic inclusion(i suppose). -Thanks Nagesh

Comment: @NageshBorate yes if its not part  of exclusion list then it will be included.